# How to set constant member value of class by taking user input?

Tags: c++, class

```js
class person
{
public:
 person(string var):name(var){}
 void input()
 {
  string var;
  cout << "Enter your name: ";
  getline(cin, var);
  person temp(var);
  this->name = temp.name;
 }
private:
 const string name;
};
```

I am trying to set constant member of class (which is private) by taking user input which is done by a function named input (in public), C++ allows us to assign constant variable to other constant variable but in class I am using this pointer to do this thing but it gives error.

Comment: if you're setting it at runtime, then it's not a constant. it's a variable, even if you only ever set it once.

Comment: Your question is very hard to read, please show some example code.

Answer (score 2):

> ... and I do not use constructor to do this thing. Can this thing is possible in C++ ?

No, it's not possible. `const` class member values need to be determined at construction time.

Comment: but c++ allows us to assign constant variable to other constant variable.

Comment: @jonny Not for `const` class members.

Answer (score 0):

keyword const is infact used for the same reason, i.e. its value can't be changed throughout its lifetime or throughout the variable is in its scope...

so a variable decalred as const , its value cant be changed either in code(other than in declaration ) nor at runtime